# Missing DOI search at select entry type

Tags: jabref

So I have successfully downloaded the latest JabRef onto my Ubuntu 16.04 system and wanted to enter an article I am citing into JabRef. However, the doi search option seems not to exist (see attached picture). Has anyone got a clue how I can enable/use this feature?

It worked perfectly fine on my windows 10 system.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you using version 4.2? On my Windows machine the DOI picker is there. You may want to try to file a bug report directly at https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/

Comment: See https://github.com/koppor/jabref/blob/master/jabref-in-debian.md for the current status of the deb package in Debian and thus in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, the JabRef I have of version 2.10. As Christoph said below in the answer, I will try using the jar version. Will keep you guys notified! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the jar version. If you installed JabRef from the repos you probably gave gotten an old version of JabRef.